# Google Sheets right() in Sum in Arrayformula returning false values

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I've a column of sample data where each cell is either blank or (3 alpha chars, 1 white space, 1 digit). For example:

[image]

I need to check if the cell begins with "GTR" or "DBT", then return the number, and sum the return of the column. I'm using the formula below:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(IF(OR(left(A1:A10,3)="GTR",left(A1:A10,3)="DBT"),VALUE(right(A1:A10,1)),0)))
```

**The problem is that instead of returning 20, it returns 52.**

In fact it appears to return the last char of any cell in the range. (eg. if "A5" has a value of 'someText' the formula returns an error because `value()` can't parse 't' into a number.

### I'd like to know if anyone can tell me how to solve this problem, or if there's something wrong with my formula?

**Here's an example of this problem in a Google Sheet:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XNVUWhI43UW2ABrja8rmplmxhhkSu-je45F-9F_3GQM/edit#gid=0

Thanks,
Onji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ArrayFormula` plus `OR` will evaluate to TRUE if any of the cells in the range is in the codition, to overcome this remove the `OR`, and add an `IF` for every condition, as such:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(IF(left(A1:A10;3)="GTR";VALUE(right(A1:A10;1));0);IF(left(A1:A10;3)="DBT";VALUE(right(A1:A10;1));0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution of Kriggs, this formula should also work:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(if(regexmatch(B3:B12, "GTR|DBT")=TRUE, right(B3:B12)+0,)))
```

Comment: Thanks JPV, I think I'll switch to this. Regex syntax is much more readable than nested if/or/and formulae :)